# Typescript collected properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to figure out how to do this but I'm not sure how
Is it possible to type func such that the args are actually the types collected by the spread?

```
function callNTimes({ n, func, ...args }: NTimeProps): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        func(index, args);
    }
}

type NTimeProps = {
    n: number;
    func: (index: number, args/*the collected args hopefully*/) => void;
    args: Record<string, unknown>;
};
```

Ideally with this type I can then do the following

```
callNTimes({
    n: 3,
    name: "bob",
    func: (i, { name /*typescript knows name is in here*/ }) => console.log(name),
});
```

I would almost want to do this but this is obviously not correct

```
type NTimeProps = {
    n: number;
    args: Record<string, unknown> as Args;
    func: (index: number, args:Args) => void;
};
```

This is a contrived example because the relevant code is a little big.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can almost do it like this:

```js
type NTimeProps<P> = P & {
    n: number;
    func: (index: number, args: P) => void;
}
function callNTimes<P>({ n, func, ...args }: NTimeProps<P>): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        func(index, args);
    }
}
```

This however complains that the generic `P` could be instantiated with properties `n` and `func` which get omited by the way it is used so it doesn't quite represent the correct type (like calling `callNTimes<{n:string}>(...)` would be valid typescript code that wouldn't work properly) and I haven't been able to find a working example that can `Omit` those properties from the generic without totally breaking inference.

Another way that almost works is by using an interface that uses `this` to implicitly refer to own variables but I can't get this to work with automatic inference either:

```js
interface NTimeProps {
    n: number;
    func: (index: number, args: Omit<this, keyof NTimeProps>) => void;
}
function callNTimes<P extends NTimeProps>({ n, func, ...args }: P): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        func(index, args);
    }
}
```

The idea is that the interface `NTimeProps` can be extended and what ever extension it defines (extra properties) will then be expected to input to the `func` method, however this also breaks inference.
[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIBVgFsIAUoD2ADgM7IDeAUMjciAFx0CuWARtANzW0xMgKMAFKAAmEAB6MQLdlAA0yOFADmJRgHkswMAB4wAC2AkFAawgBPAjDSYc+YiQB8ASmQBeR8gBuBYCK4AvpS8-GDABCDICHAANjEY2BAkOrjIEpAgImQJdoSkjoLkdAohCAoAdJVKqsgBjLjOjD5+FNw0MARQyIIxEGDIohLuyAAMHAOZQzp044PiANTzrlS0q8ilwpPiCtUkzlyrQUHRcTlJhW10jADMcpcgcDiMAESsBKzPd6ulQsAKRQ8cMgAPQAKjA5iISQQUGARH6JhABAA7mRASgjBNkPpoBBQcDaq4PFEIiQCL1yjECMpBOjnHcAvtKMzQJBYIgUGd7KQAPpeABMKU8K1oDGYbE4lx+3TmUhk0B2KjUyAa7k8zX8l129UoQVKYQiUVi8VsST5gtwBQBJT4ZUUStqjC5eRI5qFjW8vhErW+nW6vX6c2GYwmYnEyGmIFmW0Wy0u31tmzDitUTMOuuZJxNiVdAouqzFty1SsY5HRLzeHwCXx4tt+-zojxQYOQBkxyM6JjIyigEDg-XxjLVJJAZIpVJpdIZ+yAA)

I'm not sure if this is possible with typescript right now, You basically want it to find the type of all fields in the object **except for `func`** then apply that knowledge to the arguments of `func`, however typescript isn't really built to deal with co-varient positional data like this (that they are in the same level of nesting makes this hard) for example if you put all the arguments in a seperate field of its own this becomes relatively easy:

```js
interface NTimeProps_v2<P> {
    n: number;
    func: (index: number, args: P) => void;
    args: P
}
function callNTimes_v2<P>({ n, func, args }: NTimeProps_v2<P>): void {
    for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        func(index, args);
    }
}

callNTimes_v2({
    n: 3,
    args: {name: "bob"},
    func: (i, { name /* this works great */}) => console.log(name),
});
```

This works because before knowing the type of the entire object it can determine what the `args` field is and then once that is fully resolved it can use that to help you out for the `func` input, but with your current design it can't resolve the type that the arguments are stored in without also having to resolve the `func` signature which means it has to know the type of the function in order to know the arguments and this is detected as a circular constraint (even with the `Omit` etc. because typescript isn't that clever) so inference doesn't work properly.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler isn't always able to infer both generic type parameters and unannotated callback parameter types in the same object at the same time; I think [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872#issuecomment-651450956) from [ms/TS#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) is a good example of this sort of limitation. I would definitely suggest refactoring.